# android display arraylist items in dialog

Tags: android-sqlite, android-alertdialog

I am having an arraylist fetching name and status of a person. Arraylist is storing the status and name. Its displaying one name at a time. How can I be able  to display multiple names at once in alert dialog?

```
private ArrayList getunfiledRogspDoctorList() {
    SqlDataStore sd = new SqlDataStore(this);
    sd.open();
    String gspQuery = " SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_DOCTOR + " WHERE " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS + " == " + 0 + " AND " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_DATE_ID + " = '" + selectionID + "'";
    Cursor gspCu = sd.getData(gspQuery);
    if(gspCu.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            rogspname = gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.DOCTOR_CONTACTNAME));
            unfiledrogspDoctorList.add(gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS)) + rogspname);
        }while (gspCu.moveToNext());

    }
    gspCu.close();
    sd.close();
    System.out.println("unfiledrogspDoctorList "+unfiledrogspDoctorList);

    return unfiledrogspDoctorList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code, you are having an `ArrayList` of your target display `String` in `unfiledrogspDoctorList`:

```java
// Suggest to also define the type of your returning ArrayList
private ArrayList<String> getunfiledRogspDoctorList() {
    // Define a local ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> unfiledrogspDoctorList = new ArrayList<>();
    SqlDataStore sd = new SqlDataStore(this);
    sd.open();
    String gspQuery = " SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_DOCTOR + " WHERE " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS + " == " + 0 + " AND " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_DATE_ID + " = '" + selectionID + "'";
    Cursor gspCu = sd.getData(gspQuery);
    if(gspCu.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            rogspname = gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.DOCTOR_CONTACTNAME));
            unfiledrogspDoctorList.add(gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS)) + rogspname);
        }while (gspCu.moveToNext());

    }
    gspCu.close();
    sd.close();
    System.out.println("unfiledrogspDoctorList "+unfiledrogspDoctorList);

    return unfiledrogspDoctorList;
}
```

You can consider to convert your `ArrayList` of `String` into just a `String`.

```java
private String concat(ArrayList<String> unfiledrogspDoctorList) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String item : unfiledrogspDoctorList) {
    sb.append(item);
    sb.append(","); // Or change into other separate you would like to display
  }
  sb.setLength(Math.max(0, sb.length() - 1)); // Remove the appending character
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can make use of an `AlertDialog` to display that concatenated `String`.

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder
  .setMessage(concat(getunfiledRogspDoctorList()))
  .setCancelable(false)
  .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      // Do anything upon pressing OK button
    }
   );
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Its displaying twice..Please file for Dr 0A,0B,0A,0B

Comment: You mean the AlertDialog is displaying the String list twice? I cannot see the attached image.

Comment: yes.. now image is visible

Comment: The ```concat(ArrayList)``` function itself should only convert the ```ArrayList``` into ```String``` and should not have duplicates. Could you show the records stored in your table or further check if the query you make is returning duplicates?

Comment: no duplicates..

Comment: Inside this function ```getunfiledRogspDoctorList()```, are you defining the variable ```unfiledrogspDoctorList``` globally? Could you define ```unfiledrogspDoctorList``` locally and try again?

Comment: now defined locally. its working correct.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use :-

```
SELECT group_concat(name) FROM ....
```

or to place each on a line you could change the default comma separator to a line feed using

```
SELECT group_concat(name,'\n') FROM ....
```

- `....` representing the rest of the SQL in the question

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat

- note that the ***GROUP*** as no GROUP BY clause is provided is a single group (and therefore output row) made up of ALL extracted rows.